# C++ Iterating through a vector of smart pointers

Tags: c++, stl, vector, smart-pointers

i have a class that has this function:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<PrimShapeBase> sp_PrimShapeBase; 



class Control{
     public:
         //other functions
         RenderVectors(SDL_Surface*destination, sp_PrimShapeBase);
     private:
         //other vars
          vector<sp_PrimShapeBase> LineVector;

};

//the problem of the program

void Control::RenderVectors(SDL_Surface*destination, sp_PrimShapeBase){
    vector<sp_PrimShapeBase>::iterator i;

    //iterate through the vector
    for(i = LineVector.begin(); i != LineVector.end(); i ++ ){
      //access a certain function of the class PrimShapeBase through the smart
      //pointers
      (i)->RenderShape(destination); 

    }
}
```

The compiler tells me that the class boost::shared_ptr
has no member called 'RenderShape' which I find bizarre since the 
class PrimShapeBase certainly has that function but is in a different header file.
What is the cause of this?

Comment: Any particular reason you're separating the declaration of the iterator from its initialization? Do you need `i` later? Why not `for (vector<sp_PrimShapeBase>::iterator i = LineVector.begin()` or even better `for (auto it = LineVector.begin()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't you mean

```
(*i)->RenderShape(destination);
```

?

`i` is the iterator, `*i` is the `shared_ptr`, `(*i)::operator->()` is the object.

Comment: Weird, he had the parentheses, so it seems like he either mistyped (but then what would cause the problem, not sure)...

Comment: ofcourse, how pathetic to let that slip through. derefrencing the iterator. appreciated

Comment: I can not find any place to explain, why we need to double dereference, instead of using `->` which should IMO recur until it hits true pointer object (or is `shared_ptr` considered to be pointer?). Could you please explain?

Comment: @sukhmel does `std::iterator` have an overloaded `operator->`?

Comment: it does not have an overload, although this operator is defined for iterator, as far as I can understand. Do you mean, that recurring appears only where `->` is overloaded?

Comment: @sukhmel if the iterator has defined `operator->`, that's an overload. If not, how can it be called on that object?

Answer (score 7):

That's because `i` is an iterator.  Dereferencing it once gives you the smart pointer, you need to double dereference it.

```
(**i).RenderShape(destination);
```

or

```
(*i)->RenderShape(destination);
```

Comment: If only *dereference* was a postfix operator, then we could have written `i*->RenderShape(destination);` :)

Comment: Or some ungodly thing like `i->->RenderShape(destination);`

Comment: How about introducing some syntactic sugar like `i-->RenderShape(destination);`? The longer the arrow, the more dereference steps? :)

Comment: I briefly entertained the thought while authoring my comment, but that would of course be abused in horrible ways. :O

Comment: @FredOverflow Unless of course it's `i--->RenderShape()`, in which case it would dereference the previous element.