# Why do I need to dereference iterator to smart pointer twice instead of using operator->()?

Tags: c++11, iterator, containers, smart-pointers

Suppose I have a following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <memory>

struct Test
{
    int test;
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Test>> deque;
    deque.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Test>(new Test{10}));
    auto start = deque.begin();
    std::cout << start->test << std::endl;               // <- compilation error
    std::cout << (start.operator->())->operator->()->test << std::endl; // <- OK
}
```

Why is smart-pointer treated as if it would be regular pointer object, although it is not (as far, as I understand)? From what I know, `operator->()` should recur until it reaches `T*`.

Here are some related questions [on how arrow overloading works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677804/how-arrow-operator-overloading-works-internally-in-c) and [that we need to dereference twice instead of an arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960631/c-iterating-through-a-vector-of-smart-pointers/).

Comment: The reapplication talked about there only refers to when `operator->` returns a non-pointer. The iterator's `operator->`  returns a pointer to the value which then needs to be dereferenced again. If it returned a reference to the value it would chain. BTW, I prefer `(*start)->test`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an iterator `it`, the expression `it->m` is equivalent to `(*i).m`, technically it means that the iterator's `operator->` returns a **raw pointer** to the contained object. In your case it means it returns a raw pointer to the `unique_ptr`. A final `operator->` is applied to that and you end up with a reference to the contained object. This is why no further chaining of `operator->` occurs.

Comment: this "equivalent" thing in case of iterators still seems a little odd to me, sadly. But this explanation seems to fit well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow operator is [overloaded for unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*). Because you have an iterator, you are dereferencing to a `unique_ptr`, not the object owned by it. Therefore, you need to dereference twice.

```
std::cout << (*start)->test << std::endl;
```

Comment: if `operator->` would return `unique_ptr` by reference, `operator->` would fall through to the object pointed, as this is how it works (recurs until pointer is met). So it does not really explains anything.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` are implemented to store a pointer and behave like a C pointer, while iterators also are pointers themselves.

So why you need to dereference twice? Simply because you have a pointer to pointer to `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Its exactly the same as if you have a container of plain pointers:

```
std::deque<Test*> dq;
dq.push_back(new Test{10});
auto start = dq.begin();
std::cout << (*start)->test << std::endl;
```